# React js composition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react Js and try to understand how to do composition on data I obtained from different sources, via ajax (as explained here: [Reactjs - loadResourcesFromServer - combine two sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626716/reactjs-loadresourcesfromserver-combine-two-sources)).

I have a Comment object and an Author object.

```
var Author = React.createClass({
    ...
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div><a>{this.state.data.username}</a><img src="{this.state.data.picture}" /></div>
        );
    }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
    ...
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div><p>{this.state.title}</p></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Calling < Author /> and < Comment /> return 2 separate divs, but I want to display something like

```
<div>
    <p>
        <img src="{this.state.data.picture}" />
        {this.state.title}, published by {this.state.data.username}
    </p> 
</div>
```

I tried to use a wrapper

```
<CommentWithAuthor>
    <Author/>
    <Comment/>
</CommentWithAuthor>
```

but can only access the props of the objects in this wrapper, not the objects themselves. I cannot use refs since I need a new renderer ([React.js - access to component methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods)).

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to get data from a server (you receive an object containing comments with the author and the comment value? And you want to assign those values to Author and Comment correspondingly? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hi rmuller, I try to mix the values of two ajax results in one object displaying html, ie   <div>user photo, comment title, published by username, read x times</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some hierarchy, for example, including comment block as part of author block , passing it the author id if you have more than one author and selecting the comment based on the author

```
var Author = React.createClass({
    ...
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div><img src="{this.state.data.picture}" />
                 <comment authoriid={this.props.id}/>
                 <a>{this.state.data.username}</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

that way you are sending down data from top level (author) to next level as intended by design in reactjs

Comment: Ok thanks arkoak, +1 for the hierarchy. An idea on how to do it if I have multiple elements of the comment to return, ie  <div>comment title, published by username, read x times</div>? thanks!

Comment: please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28320488/724913 , the jsfiddle has a data array which is used for looping and displaying all data. you will need to do the same with comments as your data array